# Making HTTP request using OkHttp library inside doInBackground() of AsyncTask blocks UI operation

Tags: android, okhttp

I was trying making OkHttp request in AsyncTask using call.execute() -- Synchronous call.

I have two buttons in my layout. Pressing button1 starts AsyncTask, that executes OkHttp request.call.execute().

And pressing button2, I just update a TextView.

**Observation**: While AsyncTask is running, I can not update TextView.

But, if I don't use AsyncTask and use OkHttpClient.newCall().enqueue() method,then I can update TextView by pressing button2.

Any answer for "Why using AsyncTask in this case not working"?

Source Code Sample:

```
bpost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpost);
    bpost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;
            tv.setText(""+i);
        }
    });


bstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();

            byte[] image = new byte[0];
            try {
                image = handler.execute(url).get();
                if (image != null && image.length > 0) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    tv.setText("Total btytes download: " + image.length);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tv.setText("sorry, something went wrong!");
            }
        }


public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder.url(params[0]);
        Request request = builder.build();



        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().bytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Thread.sleep() or wait() anywhere.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @M4R1KU : See source code now.

Comment: @jankigadhiya : See source code now.

Comment: @jankigadhiya : Posted code for that also.

Comment: @jankigadhiya: No, I just want to keep pressing button bpost and my TextView should be updated with a new value. But, it is not happening, until AsyncTask finishes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `get()` method of `AsyncTask` waits for the computation to finish in `doInBackground` method and then retrieves its result. See this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()).

This will make your main `UIThread` in wait mode until `doInBackground` finish its execution or there is some exception occur(i.e. `CancellationException`,`ExecutionException` and `InterruptedException`).

You should use `onPostExecute(Result)` override method of `AsyncTask`.

```
private class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
            builder.url(params[0]);
            Request request = builder.build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().bytes();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
            super.onPostExecute(bytes);
            try {
                if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    tv.setText("Total btytes download: " + bytes.length);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tv.setText("sorry, something went wrong!");
            }
        }
    }
```